# how many audiences can be push into a single journey builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Regarding Marketing Cloud Journey Builder, how many audiences can be pushed into a single journey builder at the same time? what's the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

you can push as many number of audiences as you want at the same time, there is no limitation for an audience to enter a journey.

**best practices:**

1. journey must have an entry source configured prior to successful activation.
2. Once the journey is ready, use Test Mode to test the journey flow.
3. Use only one of these three methods to admit contacts from a single event source data extension: via API, via Automation Studio’s Fire Event activity, or set a schedule during Journey Builder’s entry event setup process.
4. When a shared data extension is used as the event source data extension in more than one business unit, Journey Builder separates the processing of the data extension for each business unit.

**Note:**

to know more about **entry event**. click [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/)

to know more about the **journey best practic**e. click [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/entry_sources/entry_events/entry_events_and_data_extensions/) and scroll down to the bottom

to know more about testing a journey in **Test Mode**.Click [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/testing_an_interaction/)

Comment: How do you push more than one audience into a single journey?